# I want to disable/hide applications on mobile, based on user selection from my application

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an application where the user get to see a list of applications available in the mobile and check them, so that the checked applications will be hidden once the user clicks the `ÖK` button.

I already developed retrieving the list of applications in the mobile part. However, when I searched in google for hiding apps, I could not find any solution for that. I read in one suggestion, where it says to use `Package Manager` `setApplicationEnabledSetting`, but I couldn't find a sample for it either.

I will be so glad if anyone can let me know of a method and a sample to achieve this.

Comment: This is not generally possible. An arbitrary app has no authority over other apps, such as preventing them from running or other aspects of "hiding". You could look at the device admin or device owner APIs and see if there is something that you can use.

Comment: Then once i get permission from device manager, how may i proceed with the hiding task? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

at first i think you need os admin permission to access to apps list and hide apps icon

i wish below link help you to hide an app:

https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/hideunhide-app-icon-programmatically-android/

however if you hide an app icon in menu, user can see apps list complete in setting app part and you will need set password to open settings parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however the sample you sent tells a method to hide the icon of my application and not the icon of other applications in the phone. Do you have any other idea? Also i would like to know what you meant by, " user can see apps list complete in setting app part and you will need to set password to open settings part"?

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea but I saw in some situations and I'm sure it is possible